# How to use a XML file as a resource to read and write from in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, xml, resources, linq-to-xml

I am writing a small Windows Form Application (in C#) which uses a few resources. One of the resources is a XML file.

This XML file is supposed to be read before initialization of the first Form.
The contents of the XML file is used to create objects which are used by the application.

Normally I would add this XML file as a resource in Visual Studio.

> Project Properties > Resources > Files > Add Existing File

Then in the application I can read the contents of the XML file with: `XDocument.Parse(Resources.NameOfXMLResource)`

In this application I want to make it possible to add or update the objects, which should also update the stored information in the XML file. I know that I cannot save the updated XML file to `Resources.NameOfXMLResource` because it is actually a string containing all the contents of the XML file.

I've seen many posts about XML as resource in a C# project, but most of those posts are only about reading from the resource and not writing to it.

So my question is: How can I set-up the XML file ..

- as a resource which I can read/write;

or

- to store it somewhere in the installation folder when I run my setup.msi which installs the .exe (the application) on the desired location. *(With this approach I need to have read/write access and be able to debug the project without installing first)*

---

My current code for reading/writing to the XML file:

```
this.file = Resources.XMLItemList;

public List<ItemModel> GetStoredItems()
{
  return (from item in XDocument.Load(this.file).Descendants("Item")
          select new ItemModel
          {
            Name = item.Attribute("Name").Value,
            ID = item.Element("ID").Value,
            Description = item.Element("Description").Value,
            Size = Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("Size").Value),
            Path = item.Element("Path").Value
          }).ToList();
}

public string AddItem(ItemModel item)
{
  try
  {
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(this.file);
    xdoc.Element("Items").Add(new XElement("Item",
                              new XAttribute("Name", item.Name),
                              new XElement("ID", item.ID),
                              new XElement("Description", item.Description),
                              new XElement("Size", item.Size),
                              new XElement("Path", item.Path)));
    xdoc.Save(this.file);
    return null;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return string.Format(Resources.ErrCanNotAddItemToXML, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reading and writing a resource file sounds like a difficult (if not impossible) way to achieve what you need.  Resources are compiled into the DLL (read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984281%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Don't you think a simple XML file or your own custom Section would suffice? As far as the installer is concerned, I am confused as to why you would want to debug an "installed" version of your program?

Comment: @Ruskin, I was already afraid that it might not be possible to achieve as a Resource. What I ment with the debug part is that when I build and run the program (without creating the installer) it will run the .exe from the ./bin/debug folder. In this case the path to the XML file can not be found. When I use the installer the path can be found. (But then I do not have write permission)

Comment: Ah right, well your installer can/should be decoupled with your program.  When you run via the debugger you can simply copy the file into out directory by using the "Copy to output directory" directive on the file.  This path *should* be passed into as a parameter into the module which does reading/writing of that file.  Now where the installer puts that file is irrelevant :).  Yes, you will need to sort out your access rights during installation but that's a separate issue :).

Comment: Ah, yes. I had the "Build Action" directive on 'Resource' which I had to change to 'Content'. All I have to do now is get the right permissions on the installation directory and its contents :) Thanks for pointing this out.